# Get Complete FriendsList from facebook SDK 3.15

Tags: android, facebook

How can we get complete friends list from facebook SDK 3.15? We are only able to get the list of friends who has given authentication to app.

Is there any way to get the complete list of friends of the logged in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: NO.

All new facebook apps created after 4/30/2014 are now using Graph API 2.0, and all apps created before 4/30/2014 have 1 year to migrate to Graph API 2.0.

Under Graph API 2.0, you can only get friends who are also users of your app.

Comment: Thanks Ming Li, yes what you said is correct yesterday i refereed  Facebook sdk reference document.